# Android: If statement being skipped even if condition is correct

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, if-statement

I am new to android and am creating a registration page. Since android doesn't support mysql , i created a php based script which gives out integer values for different queries.

```
2 --> successful insertion in database
-1 --> Email already used
0--> username used
```

Depending on the integer value of the response that I get from php script I do the subsequent tasks. Even though successfully inserting the values in database and the first print stament shows the values of Regresult as "2", the if statement is not working and the both else if statements are working fine.

```
/* Getting the response back from the PHPAPI and storing it in a variable */
HttpEntity entity = Response.getEntity();
String Regresult = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


/* printing value of Regresult to verify if the condition is right or wrong */
System.out.println(Regresult);

/* Registration depending upon response from Http post call */       
/* Email used works fine when Regresult = -1 */

if(Regresult.equals("-1"))
{
     Context text = getApplicationContext();
     CharSequence message = "Email already in use.";
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(text, message, duration);
     toast.show();
 }

 /* Username used work fine when Regresult = 0 */

 else if(Regresult.equals("0"))
 {
      Context text = getApplicationContext();
      CharSequence message = "Username already in use.";
      int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(text, message, duration);
      toast.show();
 }  

/* Here is the problem when Regresult= 2 , even though consition is correct the statement don't get executed */
 else if(Regresult.equals("2"))
 {
      Context text = getApplicationContext();
      CharSequence message = "Registration Successful.";
      int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(text, message, duration);
      toast.show();
      System.out.println(Regresult);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// I think it may be some spacing problem so try this way
        if(Regresult.trim().equals("-1")){
            Context text = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence message = "Email already in use.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(text, message, duration);
            toast.show();
        }else if(Regresult.trim().equals("0")){
            Context text = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence message = "Username already in use.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(text, message, duration);
            toast.show();
        }else if(Regresult.trim().equals("2")) {
            Context text = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence message = "Registration Successful.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(text, message, duration); toast.show();
        }
```